# Updating sections with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an entity named `ToDoItem`. Which has three properties:

```
@NSManaged var toDoString: String?
@NSManaged var creationDate: NSDate?
@NSManaged var isComplete: NSNumber?
```

I'm trying to create a `NSFetchedResultsController` that will display with two section depending on the `isComplete` variable. I'm able to do that successfully buy doing this:

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {

    let questionAnswerFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ToDoItem")

    let questionAnswerFetchSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)
    questionAnswerFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [questionAnswerFetchSortDescriptor]

    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: questionAnswerFetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext,
        sectionNameKeyPath:"isComplete",
        cacheName: nil)

    frc.delegate = self
    return frc
}()
```

I've also implemented the delete methods like this:

```
//
// MARK: Fetched Results Controller Delegate Methods
//
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController,
                didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo,
                          atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int,
                                         for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

    switch (type) {
    case .Insert:
        self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        break
    case .Delete:
        self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        break
    default:
        break
    }

}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch (type) {
    case .Insert:
        if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
        break;
    case .Delete:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
        break;
    case .Update:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        }
        break;
    case .Move:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }

        if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I update the `isComplete` property I get this error:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught
>   from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after
>   the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections contained in
>   the table view before the update (0), plus or minus the number of
>   sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted). with userInfo
>   (null)

Which I understand *what* this is saying, I just don't understand *why* it causing that error. I've implemented the delegate methods per the documentation.....

---

I've updated my `NSFetchedResultsController` creation to add another sortDescriptor per @wain's answer like so:

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {

        let questionAnswerFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ToDoItem")

        let isCompleteSortDescriptor   = NSSortDescriptor(key: "isComplete", ascending: false)
        let creationDateSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)

        questionAnswerFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [isCompleteSortDescriptor, creationDateSortDescriptor]

        let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(
            fetchRequest: questionAnswerFetchRequest,
            managedObjectContext: (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext,
            sectionNameKeyPath:"isComplete",
            cacheName: nil)

        frc.delegate = self
        return frc
    }()
```

I've added some breakpoints and it turns out that this delegate method is never being called:

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController,
                didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo,
                          atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int,
                                         for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

    switch (type) {
    case .Insert:
        self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        break
    case .Delete:
        self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Which is leading to the same error as posted above. Any ideas on why that would never be called??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a sort descriptor for `isComplete`. It should be the first sort descriptor, then have your date one.

Basically, the sort and the sections need to be compatible, and yours currently aren't.

Comment: You should also check exactly what delegate callbacks you get as you should be told about an update and an addition for the section and you're probably giving misleading updates to the view as a result, composite changes are awkward to manage at a fine level of detail

Comment: I've updated any question. Adding in the other sort descriptor didn't work :(

Comment: which version of swift are you using? looks like the func signature should be `func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType)`

Comment: Ah! You're right! I had copied the func signature from here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate/1622298-controller    which is different than the one you posted. Not sure if that's a misprint in the docs. (running swift 2 currently)